# Substitute in vim, with special characters

Tags: vim, substitution

I am trying to use substitute command in vim to enclose all occurences of a particular pattern

```
\cite{author1}
\cite{author2}
```

with

```
(\cite{author1})
(\cite{author2})
```

Based on other answers in stack exchangeI used the following vim command

```
%s/\\cite{(\w\+)}/(\\cite{\1})/g
```

But, no luck. It says "no matches found". I put two back slashes, one of which is supposed to be the escape character. Kindly help.

I know I could use some other editor and finish the job, but I want to know my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

please escape `()`

```
%s/\\cite{\(\w\+\)}/(\\cite{\1})/g
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a capture group to get the entire match. You can use `\0` or `&` for the whole match in the replacement portion of your substitution.

```
:%s/\\cite{\w\+}/(&)/g
```

If you do want to use a capture group, then you need to escape the capture group/parenthesis.

```
:%s/\(foo\)/(\1)/g
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s%
:h /magic
```

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44798870/1245027), normally you need escape the parentheses.

You can use [very magic mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) (`\v`) to make the regex simpler; removing the need to escape lots of the regex parts, including the parentheses for capturing:

```
%s/\v(\\cite\{\w+\})/(\1)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what every sign in a regular expression does in vim is sometimes very
difficult, especially for all the modes and configuration variables that this
depends on. For that reason, it is very important to have visual feedback about
what text are we really matching in any moment while crafting regular
expressions.

If you work with neovim, there is a special option called `inccommand` that you
can enable to live preview the matches and substitution. That way you can figure
out you errors more quickly. This feature is very likely to be included also in
vim in the future, but independently of that, you can also use simple vim to
give you visual feedback if you enable the option `incsearch`.

With `incsearch` set, you can watch the matches of / and ? while you write them
just to be sure that the pattern is correct. Later you can exploit a nice
feature from the substitution: if you leave the first section empty, the last
search will be used.

So you could first make the search:

```
/\\cite{\w\+}/(&)/g
```

In the meantime, vim will be showing you the matched text visually. Once you
are sure that the pattern is correct press enter, and finally type:

```
:%s//(\1)<Enter>
```

Also, in case you want something more powerful than this simple hack, you can go
for my plugin [Extend.vim](https://github.com/saulaxel/EXtend.vim), that can
do that and much more with great visual feedback.