# command to conditionally add character at line beginning

Tags: vim

in vim, I need to add * at the beginning of lines that starts with

```
XMMN2@xxxxx
```

where `xxxxx` means number ranging from 200 to 400

what I've been using (compromised solution) is

```
:g/^XMMN2@2\d\d/d
:g/^XMMN2@3\d\d/d
```

it would be really beneficial if they can be commented out (instead of being deleted)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Substitute in vim, with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798719/substitute-in-vim-with-special-characters)

Comment: The ability to insert characters in certain cases would be done with the `:s` substitute command, where you'd search for the value mentioned above, and replace it with the value prepended with `*`. Note that you can do this in one command using regex, rather than multiple commands. The linked question, alongside [help sites about the substitute command](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) can explain in more detail, but it will be difficult to parse if you don't understand regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do

```
:g/your pattern/s/^/*/
```

Or equivalently

```
:%s/^your pattern/*&/
```